# можно ли на mac os работать в фоновом режиме selenium

Tags: python, selenium

можно ли на mac os selenium python работать в фоновом режиме,использую chrome.
если да то как?

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример, как запустить chrome в `headless` режиме (т.е. не показывая окно браузера):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

with webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) as driver:
    driver.get("http://www.python.org")
    assert "Python" in driver.title
    print(driver.title)
```

Comment: При этом важно закрывать браузер автоматически после окончания работы.

Comment: Действительно, при копировании пропал `driver.close()`. Обновил пример.

Comment: raise WebDriverException( selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home вот такая ошибка

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке прямо говорит, что делать. Добавьте директорию с `chromedriver` в переменную окружения PATH. Если `chromedriver` y вас нет - скачайте.